# Android Button Alignment in XML off

Tags: android, xml, layout, alignment

I'm using Relative layout and I'm trying to put a button 25dp to the left of center and one 25dp to the right of it. I've put an Anchor at CenterHorizontal and then align the buttons from it. But they won't align where they suppose to. Both end up to the left of the anchor. The left one doesn't move if I change the alignvalue, the right one moves, but it's still off by about 150dp.
code (I've removed the textViews and EditTexts in the middle in this code to make it shorter):

```
    <ScrollView    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true">
    <RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <View
        android:id="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsPris"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/knapp_spara"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsPris"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/knapp_spara" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/knapp_visa"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/knapp_spara"
        android:text="@string/knapp_visa" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2QQv.png

Comment: Easiest thing to do might be to nest those two buttons in a layout.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to have multiple layouts within ScrollView?

Comment: Try it and find out?  I'm not sure.  I'm not an Android master... and I hate dealing with Android layouts...

Comment: hehe same here. =) I've misunderstood the ScrollView- rule, so the solution you gave would work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrap the two buttons with a LinearLayout or with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<ScrollView    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true">
    <RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsPris">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/knapp_spara"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:text="@string/knapp_spara" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/knapp_visa"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/knapp_spara"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/knapp_spara"
            android:text="@string/knapp_visa" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! But I shouldn't have to do that, right? Shouldn't they be aligning as I wanted them to from the beginning? (-I'm a javaRookie, trying to learn and I'd like to know if I did something wrong (if so, what), or if it's some glitch)

Comment: `Shouldn't they be aligning as I wanted them to from the beginning?` Yes, I think so, but it is more appropriate to group things and then position them where we want. The easiest way would be even to use LinearLayout. I do not know why your solution does not work.

Comment: Please always mark whatever response solved your issue so that the thread is properly marked as "Answered".

Comment: Oh, Sorry! -I forgot. -Done =)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set them all the attributes android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsPris"

because you use RelativeLayout, just set the relative position would be ok:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/knapp_spara"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsPris"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:text="@string/knapp_spara" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/knapp_visa"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mCenterAnchor"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="@string/knapp_visa" />
```

Comment: toRightOf only indicates the position horizontally, not vertically. If I don't put layout_below or alignBaseline, the button will be placed in the top of the layout.?

Comment: have you test this method? are you want to put them on the center of the layout? if this, you can set attribute centerInParent="true" for View(@+id/mCenterAnchor), and the two buttons are the same as i suggest

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. and No, I don't want them centered. I want them 25dp to the right of the center and 25dp to the left of center.